# Unable to move vertical slider by dragging

Tags: qt, qml

Hi I'm trying to implement a vertical slider. The slider is showing correctly. However, the slider handle is not moving. I have also added y: values.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Slider {

    id: temperatureControlSlider
    value: 70
    from: 55
    to: 85
    stepSize: 1
    orientation: Qt.Vertical

    background: Rectangle{
        height: parent.height
        width: 3
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    handle: Rectangle{
        y: temperatureControlSlider.visualPosition * (temperatureControlSlider.availableHeight - height)
        width: 76
        height: 76
        radius: width/2
        color: "black"
        border.color: "white"
        border.width: 3
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        Text {
             anchors.centerIn: parent
             color: "white"
             font.pixelSize: 30
             text: temperatureControlSlider.value
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I add  `anchors.fill: parent` in your slider code and it works like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Slider {
        id: temperatureControlSlider
        anchors.fill: parent
        value: 70
        from: 55
        to: 85
        stepSize: 1
        orientation: Qt.Vertical

        background: Rectangle{
            height: parent.height
            color: "#161414"
            width: 3
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        handle: Rectangle{
            y: temperatureControlSlider.visualPosition * (temperatureControlSlider.availableHeight - height)
            width: 76
            height: 76
            radius: width/2
            color: "black"
            border.color: "white"
            border.width: 3
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Text {
                 anchors.centerIn: parent
                 color: "white"
                 font.pixelSize: 30
                 text: temperatureControlSlider.value
             }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined the `height` of your Slider.

I tested your slider adding the height of `height: 200` and it is working well.
I also added a background color in your Rectangle and a border color to see the slider track.

[click to see the Slider working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYgwo.gif)

Comment: Hi. when I add height to slider it is still not moving

Comment: Has your Slider a parent? Is it "inside" another item/component?